# Retaining EditText changes when using Loaders after orientation change

Tags: android, loader, orientation-changes

I have a fragment that's used for editing a project. I load all the data with a loader and then let the user edit it. The problem is that when a user enters some data in `EditText` and then rotates the device the loader reloads the data and overrides all changes made by the user. Of course when I comment out `initLoader()` the EditText values are retained after rotation.

What are some common patterns stopping reloading of loaders after orientation change? The easiest solution I can come up with is putting some sort of a flag variable into `onSaveInstanceState()` and adding an if statement in `onLoadFinished()` to not reload the data, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution. Below is simplified code from my fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_edit_project, container, false);

    this.projectAddressInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_add_edit_project_address);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(
        getActivity(),
        Project.buildProjectUri(this.projectId),
        PROJECTION,
        null,
        null,
        null
    );
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Object data) {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) data;

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        this.projectAddressInput.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Project.COLUMN_ADDRESS)));
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {}
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `android:configChanges` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to instruct Activity Manager not to restart your activity on configuration changed (which as a result will reload your `CursorLoader`):

```
<activity
    ...
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
```

> If your application doesn't need to update resources during a specific configuration change and you have a performance limitation that requires you to avoid the activity restart, then you can declare that your activity handles the configuration change itself, which prevents the system from restarting your activity.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: That works fine when the fragment has 1 layout for all screen sizes. In my case I have 2 different layouts (portrait and landscape), how can I handle layout changes in `onConfigurationChanged` without reloading the loader but keeping the data in the layout?

Comment: In that case i'm not sure if it's possible, since you have no choice but to restart the activity to recreate new view. In my case, I construct my layout so that it's adaptive to both orientations (the landscape version contains the portrait version + something else), thus I don't have to restart my activity.

Comment: I guess another option is to save all values in `onSaveInstanceState()` and add them to the layout if after reload they are not null.

Comment: That would be `onConfigurationChanged()`, but again, you need to recreate your activity to apply the new orientation layout so it wouldn't help. I guess in your case you can still `initLoader()`, but `onLoadFinished()` have a check to see if your `savedInstanceState` is not null to decide whether to set text?

Comment: Yeah that could potentially work. I'll give it a go and if it doesn't work/gets too complex I'll just change the view to fit both portrait and landscape as there isn't much going on in that view anyway. It's weird that there is no easier way to do this as it seems like a fairly common case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll leave the question open for a few hours and if nobody comes up with a better solution I'll accept your answer. Thanks again.